# how to prevent google search auto focus on keypress?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am making extension for myself, and I want to disable auto focus or at least run my function before it get focused.

I have tried targeting these events : `keypress, keyup, keydown, input` on `window` and `document`. And stop event by using this:

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', stopEvent);

document.addEventListener('keyup', stopEvent);

document.addEventListener('keydown', stopEvent);

document.addEventListener('input', stopEvent);


document.body.addEventListener('keypress', stopEvent);

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', stopEvent);

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', stopEvent);

document.body.addEventListener('input', stopEvent);


window.addEventListener('keypress', stopEvent);

window.addEventListener('keyup', stopEvent);

window.addEventListener('keydown', stopEvent);

window.addEventListener('input', stopEvent);

function stopEvent(e) {
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault()
return false;
}
```

But somehow input box for search still gets selected, do i need to somehow remove all event handlers?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, it's The 3rd parameter.

`useCapture` 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

took me like 2 minutes to solve this after some cardio.

```
function stopEvent(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    //e.stopPropagation();
    //e.preventDefault()
    //return false;
}

//var eles  = [window, document, document.body];
var eles  = [window];

eles.forEach(function(ele){
    ele.addEventListener('keypress',stopEvent,true);
    ele.addEventListener('keyup',stopEvent,true);
    ele.addEventListener('keydown',stopEvent,true);
    ele.addEventListener('input',stopEvent,true);
});
```